# Linux bash inline command to execute a program and limit the resource

Tags: php, linux, bash, runtime, memory-limit

I made a website that needs to execute some kind of C++ program (the program has been compiled). But I want to limit the resources needed by the program. The resources that I want to limit are run time and used memory.
I think run time can be done with `command to execute & sleep time; kill $!`
But that command causes some delay if the process finishes before the sleep time.

I don't know how to limit run time (without delay) and used memory with an inline command.
Is there any suggestion to do it?

Thx before...
I really appreciate your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command `ulimit` is your friend

for example `(ulimit -t 1; /your/program 2>/some/logfile) | head -c 100k`

will do two things:

- limit the max CPU to one second
- limit the output to 100k

Comment: Thx for your explaination...
If you don't mind, I wanna ask again..
the ulimit is work. I like that, but head is not working...
'head : illegal byte count -- 100k'

Comment: this does not limit used memory at all

Comment: so, how can I limit the used memory?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `ulimit` command. I've not used it but I think it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ulimit -d 1000 -m 1000 -v 1000 -t 1; /your/program 2>/some/logfile) | head -c 100000
```

This will limit memory size as well as time. You can use `ulimit -a` to find out what these limits mean or read the bash man page and search for ulimit.

Comment: that's working..
thanks for your answer..
but, why my log file empty?
I tried to give the time limit shorter than my program's run time, but, when it stop, why my logfile empy??